# System.assertException while deploying apex trigger handler class & test class to other environment

Tags: unit-test, base64

Email to case is getting created in salesforce from other system and the case subject has the following format : **"?utf-8?b?QW5vbWFseSBkZXRIY3Rpb24g4oCTIERFIFNIQVc?="**  So am converting into string as below using EncodingUtil class.

Apex trigger handler class logic:

```java
String s= case.subject;
String s1 = s.substring(10);
String s2 = s1.removeEnd('?=');
Blob b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(s2);
String finalText = b.toString();
Case.subject = finalText;
```

TEST CLASS:

```java
static testMethod void subjectDecoding(){
    Start test.startTest();
    Case c = new case();
    c.status = 'New';
    c.origin = 'Email';
    c.subject= '=?utf-8?b?QW5vbWFseSBkZXRIY3Rpb24g4oCTIERFIFNIQVc?=';
    c.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('query').getRecordTypeId();
    Insert c;

    c = [select subject from case where id IN :c.Id]
    Test.stoptest();
    system.assertEquals('Anomaly detection – DE SHAW', c.subject);
}
```

When I run the above test class it is passing and covering 100% coverage in dev environment, but when am deploying to other environment this `system.assert` statement failing the test class
`system.assertException('Anomaly detection – DE SHAW', '=?utf-8?b?QW5vbWFseSBkZXRIY3Rpb24g4oCTIERFIFNIQVc?=')`

In place of actual am getting the encoded value.

Comment: Your question has some issues in it that make it hard to understand, and your test method has some syntax issues too. You should stop using the `testMethod` keyword as it is deprecated. Instead you should be using the `@isTest` annotation for test methods (as well as the test class itself).

Comment: My best guess given the information given so far is that you're deploying the test class, but not the class that it's supposed to be testing. They should be getting deployed together (especially if you're making a change to the SUT, the system under test, i.e. the class where you're doing this string manipulation).

Comment: Hi Derek, sure will do the suggested changes to test class and edited the question as well, am deploying both the triggerhandler class and test class together, and these classes are new and doesn't already exist in the other environment.

Comment: did you deploy the trigger on Case?

Comment: Yes that was the issue, I was in an impression that I can manually add my trigger handler class to the existing trigger without deploying the entire trigger once again through changeset. Thank you @cropredy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your testmethod line:

```
Insert c;
```

assumes that the trigger for Contact will execute that in turn will execute your triggerHandler.

But, if you deploy

- the testmethod
- the trigger handler

but not

- the trigger

then the testmethod fails because the triggerHandler never executed as there's no trigger

*This is a common mistake, and one I've made myself more than once!*

Comment: Well explained, thank you. But couldn't upvote your answer, as am getting a popup that "you would need 15 reputation to caste a vote."

Comment: @Sweetie - you should be able to accept the answer by clicking the check mark, even with `rep = 1`